# Change column names only for display purpose

Tags: r

Not sure if this can be achieved. I have a vector called `col`.

```
col <- ("wert","gfr","sFred")
```

But actually i do not need this column names to be displayed in my shiny application, instead i need below the column names to be replaced by `new_col`  respectively. For example, in place if "wert", i need "WERT", in place of "gfr", I need "GTY" and so on . Is it possible to achieve? I mean only for the display purpose

```
col <- ("wert","gfr","sFred")
new_col <- ("WERT","GTY", "FRE")
```

Usage below

```
> List_new <- purrr::map(col, ~fluidRow(h4(""),column(width = 12,textInput(.,.,value = 2)),))
> List_new
[[1]]
<div class="row">
  <h4></h4>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
      <label class="control-label" for="wert">wert</label>
      <input id="wert" type="text" class="form-control" value="2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

[[2]]
<div class="row">
  <h4></h4>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
      <label class="control-label" for="gfr">gfr</label>
      <input id="gfr" type="text" class="form-control" value="2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

[[3]]
<div class="row">
  <h4></h4>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
      <label class="control-label" for="sFred">sFred</label>
      <input id="sFred" type="text" class="form-control" value="2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you run above code in HTML you get 3 boxes with names. These names need to be changed as I defined in new_col.

Comment: Where are you using this in Shiny? The best answer depends on what the display is

Comment: Please see my edited question along with my explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use either map2 or a named vector

```
map2(col, new_col, ~{fluidRow(h4(""),column(width = 12,textInput(.x,.y,value = 2)),)})
```

This will make the inputid col for referencing in your code, the label which is only UI will be the new_col

Or you can name the vector

```
names(col) <- new_col

 purrr::map(col, ~fluidRow(h4(""),column(width = 12,textInput(.,names(.),value = 2)),))
```

Personally I would prefer the names option because it keeps everything together in 1 object

Comment: can we set a limit to textInput so that it takes maximum of 4 characters only?

Comment: Yes the simplest implementation uses javascript, look around on stackoverflow, there are a ton of examples